# Why doesn't Lerna symlink my dependencies?

Tags: javascript, lerna, monorepo

I've recently migrated a large JS project to a JS monorepo. I've updated the package.json file in each of the packages to use the same version for hoisting.

```
 rwxr-xr-x    - mridang 21 Jan 12:51 ├── packages
drwxr-xr-x    - mridang 21 Jan 14:30 │  ├── admin-customer-import
drwxr-xr-x    - mridang 21 Jan 14:30 │  ├── admin-tools
drwxr-xr-x    - mridang 21 Jan 14:30 │  ├── mycommoncode
```

Both `admin-customer-import` and `admin-tools` have these in the dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "mycommoncode": "*",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
    "vuex": "^3.6.0"
  }
```

When I run `npx lerna bootstrap --hoist` - it completes successfully but then only creates symlinks for the `mycommoncode` shared package inside the respective `node_modules` folder.

If I run `npx lerna boostrap` - it installs the same dependencies (not symlinks) in each of the `node_modules` directories.

What am I doing wrong? I've been through the docs but I cannot get the deps symlinked.

Comment: This looks like it should work. From which directory are running `npx`?

Comment: Could you also post your lerna config?